# Get the nearby objects of array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So, I have data. It is array of objects.

```
data = [
  {
    "id": "200",
    "price": "5000"
  },
  {
    "id": "137",
    "price": "8000"
  },
  {
    "id": "230",
    "price": "9000"
  },
  {
    "id": "241",
    "price": "9000"
  },
  {
    "id": "78",
    "price": "10000"
  }
]
json=JSON.parse(data);
```

I make something like pager.

My code should return nearby (previous and next) elements of original element.

It is not allowed to change order of objects.

I'm trying to do something like

```
json.indexOf(JSON.parse('{"id":"200","price":"5000"}'))
```

but it returns `-1`.

Also `json[0]==JSON.parse('{"id":"200","price":"5000"}')` return `false`, but I think that this elements are similar.

What way do you see?

```js
json=JSON.parse('[{"id":"200","price":"5000"},{"id":"137","price":"8000"},{"id":"230","price":"9000"},{"id":"241","price":"9000"},{"id":"78","price":"10000"}]');
console.log(json.indexOf(JSON.parse('{"id":"200","price":"5000"}')));
console.log(json[0]==JSON.parse('{"id":"200","price":"5000"}'));
console.log(json[0]);
console.log(JSON.parse('{"id":"200","price":"5000"}'));
```

Comment: is `id` unique?

Comment: @NinaScholz, yes

Comment: you cannot do `json[0]==JSON.parse('{"id":"200","price":"5000"}')` because two objects are never equal, same is the case when you try with indexOf, so i think you have to filter your array on the basis of some object's property.You can filter by 'id' or 'price' here. Use filter method with index
See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @AbhishekKumar, so, there are no way to get nearby elements without cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a function which finds the index of the wanted `id` and returns items before that index, the index and one after the index with adjustment at the beginning of the array.

```js
function getParts(id) {
    var index = array.findIndex(o => o.id === id),
        min = Math.max(index - 1, 0);

    if (index !== -1) {
        return array.slice(min, min + (index ? 3 : 2));
    }
}

var array = JSON.parse('[{"id":"200","price":"5000"},{"id":"137","price":"8000"},{"id":"230","price":"9000"},{"id":"241","price":"9000"},{"id":"78","price":"10000"}]');

console.log(getParts('200'));
console.log(getParts('137'));
console.log(getParts('230'));
console.log(getParts('78'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i think it would work as the 'id' property is unique

```js
      var words = [{"id":"200","price":"5000"},{"id":"137","price":"8000"},{"id":"230","price":"9000"},{"id":"241","price":"9000"},{"id":"78","price":"10000"}];
        let k;
        let sayYourKeyId = "137";
        const result = words.find((word, index) => {
          if(word.id == sayYourKeyId){
          k = index;
          }
          });
        
        console.log(words[k-1]);
        console.log(words[k]);
        console.log(words[k+1]);
```